# In jmeter in my script some of login samplers are failing getting 403 error

Tags: web-applications, jmeter

i have added cookie manager in test plan,also i tried all the options present in cookie manager still i am getting 403 error in some samplers but 20 days back my scripts are worked fine could you please any one help me

Comment: may be your login credentials would have been changed the response code 403 from server says that it is unauthorized request.Need some more information for your question

Comment: Please, could you add configurations and also library versions used?

Comment: Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case the application changed, a newer version was deployed and now you need to re-create or amend your test script. Try recording the login once again using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and compare generated requests under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller) with the ones you have.

Another option is that the test stopped working due to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/), i.e. you recorded a some form of a token which has expired and now you need to refresh this token.

Comment: i have recorded new script and i compared both scripts all apis urls are recorded same the aplication session is handled by the cookies earlier if i select cookie polcy as "bestmatch" samplers got passed but now i am getting the issue 403

Comment: i have total 13 samplers for login in that credentials submission call i.e sampler passing after that 4 samplers are faliling if i check thoose calls in postman its showing 200 status code

Comment: when i check request body in recording log(httpstestscriptrecorder below view results tree) cookie data is more than request body of replay sampmpler  in replay log(httpstestscriptrecorder above view results tree)